# Почему при индексах [1],[2] и [-1],[-2] дает одинаковые результаты

Tags: python

```
>>> c=bob[0].split()
>>> c
['Bob', 'Smith']
>>> c[1]
'Smith'
>>> c[0]
'Bob'
>>> c[-1]
'Smith'
>>> c[-2]
'Bob'
```

Comment: `-1` это последний элемент, `-2` предпоследний и так далее

Comment: @andreymal , Спасибо за ответ. и за правку

Comment: @andreymal Оформите ваш комментарий более развернуто в ответе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Некоторые типы в Python вроде списков и строк поддерживают отрицательные индексы. Они позволяют брать элементы с конца: `c[-1]` это последний элемент, `c[-2]` предпоследний и так далее. Отрицательные индексы можно переписать на вычисление положительного индекса, примерно так: `c[len(c) - 1]`, `c[len(c) - 2]` и так далее.

В [документации Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) есть наглядная диаграммка, показывающая, как нумеруются символы в строке (для списков тоже применимо):

```
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+
 | P | y | t | h | o | n |
 +---+---+---+---+---+---+
 0   1   2   3   4   5   6
-6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1
```

Тем не менее, проверка на выход за пределы списка/строки всё ещё имеется:

```
>>> s = 'Python'

>>> s[6]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range

>>> s[-7]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Кстати, с помощью [расширенного синтаксиса срезов](https://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html) можно перевернуть список, если указать отрицательный шаг:

```
>>> c = ['Bob', 'Smith']
>>> c[::-1]
['Smith', 'Bob']
```